# Proving that preorder on the set of measurable functions is symmetric

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory

Let's say I have specific preorder $\prec$ on set $S$ and I want to prove that in fact it is equivalence relation. What is known already:

1. $S$ is set of measurable functions $f : \Omega \rightarrow X$ on fixed probability space $\langle \Omega, \mathfrak{I}, \mathbb{P} \rangle$ with same arbitrary finite codomain;
2. $f_1 \prec f_2 \Rightarrow \rho \circ f_1 \prec \rho \circ f_2, \forall \rho : X \rightarrow Y$;
3. It follows that $f_1 \prec f_2 \Leftrightarrow f_2 \prec f_1$ is easy to prove for any $f_2 = \pi \circ f_1$, where $\pi$ is arbitrary permutation. Trivial combinatorics — you just chain up enough $\pi \circ ... \circ \pi$ for it to cycle.

Unfortunately, I do not see any way to propagate this symmetry to general case of functions that are not mutually permutable, but maybe you can suggest some strategy? What additional facts can I try to prove here to reach my goal?

Comment: Do all of the functions in $S$ have codomain $X$, or are the codomains arbitrary?

Comment: @user44191, codomains are arbitrary, but if functions have different codomain, then they are definitely not comparable.

Comment: A suggestion on how to proceed: often, whenever you are making a statement about "all functions from X to arbitrary spaces Y", it is often a statement about a structure on X in disguise. Here, I believe the structure shouldn't be difficult to determine, and should lead to a very quick answer; as such, I think this belongs on Math.SE, not here.

Comment: @user44191, thank you for explanation - I myself specialize in game theory, so here I'm all in the dark. What particular aspects of structure you are talking about? Before formalizing it in this style, I was trying to solve my problem through measure theory, but without success. Also, can you take a glance at the answer I gave below? Can it be that statement is true?

Comment: The policy here is generally not to answer questions that belong on Math.SE. Think about it this way, though: what, exactly, will clearly guarantee that $f_1 \prec f_2 \prec f_1$, and how is that about a structure on $Omega$ rather than a structure on $X$?

Comment: Suppose that $X=\{0, 1\}$, $\Omega=[0, 1]$. Then condition 2 is satisfies if we assume that $f$ and $1-f$ are equivalent. So you can take any preorder on $\{f:[0, 1]\rightarrow\{0, 1\}: f(0)=0\}$ and extend it to a preorder satisfying 2. So in general condition 2 does not give much information.

Comment: @user44191: I do not see how a structure on $\Omega$ helps. I guess the problem is rather about the question how injective a general element of $S$ is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it needs to be an equivalence relation. For any $f \in S$, define $\operatorname{ker}(f) := \{(x_1, x_2) | f(x_1) = f(x_2)\}$. Then define $f_1 \prec f_2$ if $\operatorname{ker}(f_1) \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f_2)$. The condition given is pretty clearly true.

This is not an equivalence condition if $\Omega$ has any nontrivial measurable set.

Comment: Thank you for meaningful counterexample! It really helps in recognizing important aspects of my model. Let's say we add two additional facts:

Comment: 1. $f_1 \prec f_2 \Rightarrow \mathbb{P} \circ f_1^{-1} = \mathbb{P} \circ f_2^{-1}$;
 2. $f_1 \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{=} f_2 \Rightarrow f_1 \prec f_2 \prec f_1$.
Would it still be possible to construct counterexample?

Comment: @DoktorDiagoras 1) What is $\mathbb{P}$ here? 2) What is the superscripted equality? 3) What are the quantifiers on these new conditions?

Comment: 1) as per main question, $S$ is set of measurable functions, so $\mathbb{P}$ is some fixed measure; 2) $\stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{=}$ means equal almost everywhere under measure $\mathbb{P}$; 3) $\forall f_1, f_2 \in S$.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$ is some fixed measure on $\Omega$, of course.

Comment: For the new conditions, try $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $\mathbb{P}$ the counting measure, and have all nonequal $f$ incomparable except in the following cases: if $f(1) = f(2) = g(2) = g(3) \neq f(3) = g(1)$, then $f \prec g$. If I've understood your question and new conditions correctly, that should work, I think.

Comment: Looks like you understood correctly, yes. The problem is, that I'm yet struggling to formulate, why exactly this pattern is impossible in my model. I believe there should be some relatively simple condition covering this case, but it's hard to state it without talking in depth about what $\prec$ actually is.

Comment: OK, I have managed to define $f_1 \prec f_2$ as $I(D_{\rho}(f_1)) \subseteq I(D_{\rho}(f_2)), \forall \rho$, where function $\rho$ can have any finite domain, $D_{\rho}(f) = \{g \mid f \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{=} \rho \circ g\}$ and $I(g_1) = \{g_2 \mid \mathbb{P} \circ g_1^{-1} = \mathbb{P} \circ g_2^{-1}\}$. I strongly believe that such preorder is symmetric because of external reasons (it has game-theoretical interpretation that is definitely too complex to discuss here), but I'm unable to prove it as defined.

Comment: I have constructed even better formalization and moved it to separate question - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330990/again-proving-that-specific-preorder-on-the-set-of-measurable-functions-is-symm - it'll be more comfortable there, without clutter of half-baked stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, because I feel that I have found something. Not a proof yet, but maybe a clearer picture and plan to get to it. Is it possible that following is true?

> Given any preorder $\prec$ on a function space $\Omega \rightarrow X$, if operation $\rho \circ$ is monotonic for every $\rho : X \rightarrow X$, then $\prec$ is symmetric.

I can't find any counterexample, at least in case of finite X.